# Applying Single Table Inheritance

Tags: database-design

From [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661637/mvc-design-convention-cruding-inherited-models) StackOverflow's question:

[image: database structure]

Summarizing:

- My CRUDs are: customers, employees and branches.
- `Customer`s and `Employee`s are associated with one `Person`, one `Individual` (fields related to the person itself) and one `User` (for login purposes). So `Individual`s and `User`s are always related to one `Customer` or `Employee` person.
- `Branch`es are associated with one `Person` and one `Company` (fields related to the corporate person). So `Company`s are always related to one `Branch` person. They didn't have an user because they're affiliated to the company that this database stands for - it's their employees who can authenticate into the app.
- An `Employee` belongs to one `Branch`. A `Branch` has zero or many `Employee`s. *(yeah, diagram is incorrect, sorry!)*
- Currently I'm using a single bit to diff `Employee` role - I've employees with operational and administrative rights. Roles permissions goes in the code itself, and here you can realize that customers also have their own role... Any suggestions to implement a better (and simple) way to manage that roles for both customers and employees?

How should I change that *wrong* 3NF structure to achieve a well designed single table inheritance for a better use of MVC pattern?

**Update**

Ok, I tried to simplify it a bit, and now I accomplished this new structure:

[image: new database structure]

Can I still improve it? How?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your requirements, the `Person`, `Individual`, `Company`, and `User` tables could be combined into a single record since the relationships between these tables are all one-to-one.  Unless this is some kind of trick question...

One could go so far as to say all the tables that involve one-to-one relationships could be combined into a single table since that would eliminate the duplicate foreign keys, thereby saving space.  Having said that you'd really have to be hard pressed for space to worry about saving that small an amount of space.

It looks to me like you need to revisit your design spec with an eye for simplification.

Comment: I think company and individual are both mutually exclusive subsets of person, and same with customer and employee.  At least that's how I read his schema.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I see here is you are tracking person data, which is joined to customers and employees so with additional information there.  Rethink your mappings to branches.   It looks to my eye (not knowing what you are trying to do) like you need to do a 1:many mapping of branches to persons.  I don't know why you'd have a separate mapping to employees.

The next thing I would look at doing is encapsulating that storage inside updatable views for your MVC.  This means instead of redesigning your storage, you are encapsulating normalized storage inside of denormalized interfaces.  The MVC then expands the data model it is given through these views, but the storage logic is in your database.  This promotes data re-use.  How you do this part will be RDBMS specific however.

Comment: I've updated my question almost at the same time you answered... Yeah, branches are 1:many to costumers in the previous diagram, I've used a wrong cardinality, sorry!
I tried to simplify the database structure in the last diagram, now I think it's more easy to understand what I need... :)

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is as follows:

a) I would keep all person information in a single table whether they are customers or employees - including login information

b) Create a customer table with a link to Person, and details of when they became a customer, when they stopped being a customer, and other customer specific information

c) Create a table for employee to track employee related information

d) Create a table employeebranch so that you track the start and end information for the employee in a branch, add a column for personid so that you can easily when the person was assigned to a branch, start and end date for the assignment to the branch

e) In real life, a person may have different contact information as a customer or an employee - you can create a contact table, add a contact type - for person, customer and employee, start date and end date (addresses get invalidated)

f) Create a table roles where the roles are defined

g) Create a personroles table so that you can assign one or more roles to a person, this is irrespective of whether they are customers or employee (as the rules become more complex) it will make more sense - this is how Role Based Access (RBAC) works

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the tool you use to present your design can not express what you want to tell us. From the title of your post i think that you want to express some "is-a" relation between the entity "person" and the entities customer,employee, branch user,individual and company. But this inheritance-/isa- relation is not expressed by your diagrams and therefore the result is a lot of confusion. You took the input from this confusion and created this role based approach. I think you should solve your initial problem: express your ideas by an adequate diagram and discuss your ideas using this diagram.